# Is there any way to catch the window shaking?

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling, window, cinder

In windows 7 and windows 8 desktop mode there is a way to make your app all alone on screen - shake the window. Recently I found about great lib called Cinder. It has a very good [tutorial](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.3/hello_cinder_chapter1.html) with a cat in a window with snow!) So I wondered - how to catch and use window shake event on windows from C++ code in order to make a snow ball (I need current direction and speed of window "shake")?

Comment: You want to catch the user shaking your window? or the user shaking a window which minimizes your window?

Comment: the user shaking my window. (window with cat and snow!=))

Answer (score 3):

Your window will receive `WM_MOVING` messages with the updated window position.